# Quatz job not getting triigered in spring with Quartz

Tags: java, mysql, spring, quartz-scheduler

below is my quatz integration with Spring but it is not working i.e. Job is not getting triggered . I can see quartz is checking MySQL database in few MS so that means connection with MYSQL is fine and also records are getting inserted in tables but Sysout mentioned in below class is not coming in console. please advice what could be root cause -

**from Spring config XML**

```
<bean id="myTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="exampleBusinessObjectJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <bean name="exampleBusinessObjectJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
                <property name="name" value="exampleBusinessObjectJob"/>
                <property name="jobClass" value="com.aexp.mars.job.ExampleJob"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 */1 * * * ?"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exampleBusinessObjectJob" class="com.aexp.mars.job.ExampleJob">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>

        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="exampleBusinessObjectJobTrigger" />
            </list>        
        </property>
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MARS_SCHEDULER</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">10000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">600000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">3</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">false</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource">marsDS</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">15000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime">20</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.marsDS.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.marsDS.URL">{server_url}</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.marsDS.user">{user_name}</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.marsDS.password">{password}</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.marsDS.maxConnections">10</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.marsDS.validationQuery">select 1</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class">org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="myTaskExecutor" />
        <property name="jobFactory">
            <bean class="com.aexp.mars.job.MarsSpringBeanJobFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Java class - **

```
public class ExampleJob   {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleJob.class);


    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
          System.out.println("Job is running");
          LOG.info("Job ran");
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
          System.out.println("Job#1 is running");
          LOG.info("Job ran");
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of Quartz and Spring are you using ?

Comment: Spring 3.2 and Quartz 1.8.6

Comment: issue is resolved now  . thanks for all help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the scenario . I changed the value of cron expression to run it in every 1 minute but it was still set to my previous value (i.e. early morning 3 AM) . i added below property and then new cron expression startd working ..

```
<property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
```